# How to keep real time webpage using ejs (server to to client )? (not client to server)

Tags: mqtt

I just realized (maybe) I committed a fatal error halfway during my homemade project. It seems .ejs is not that dynamic.

I am controlling some esp8266s from a webpage, using the template engines EJS.

**What I have** - It works perfectly.

The sequence of events once I press a button on my webpage (using MQTT):

index.EJS --> index.js(client) --> RaspberryPI(Broker) --> esp8266(Client) --> led(on/off)

**What I need**

I need to display and update a temperature on my webpage from a dh11:

dh11(temp) --> esp8266(Client) --> RaspberryPI(Broker) --> index.js(client) --> index.EJS

What is the best way to keep that webpage showing in a real time the current temperature?

PS. I found one example using Pug, but I am not sure if it is the same thing. https://diyprojects.io/esp8266-web-server-fast-development-of-html-js-with-node-js-and-pug/#.XH4q_1P7ST9

Comment: Asking questions about "What is best" tend to get closed as leading to opinion based. Also you seem to already made a decision since this question is only tagged with MQTT and nothing else, why can't the page just subscribe to the MQTT data and update it's self without needing to go back to the server?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that kind of question wasn't well seen by StackOverflow. I don't want to use just a page to subscribe to the MQTT because just who has the html file can open it. I want to anyone in my network open that page without to have to install or download anything, so the solution I thought was to create a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You need Paho MQTT Javascript client https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/, it uses WebSockets to connect to an MQTT Broker and works in the browser.